# Kubernetes and WooCommerce cart issues

Tags: wordpress, kubernetes, google-compute-engine

When I run multiple instances of WordPress on Google Kubernetes Engine and drop session affinity I get weird behavior in the cart, items disappear and come back. And people get logged out. (When I use session affinity, 100% of my traffic gets sent to one pod).

It seemed to be an issue of session persistence, but from what I can tell, WordPress relies on cookies to store login and cart info rather than sessions so this shouldn't be an issue. Locally when I use docker, destroy the container, and restart my cart remains so this seems to confirm that.

What is going on? And more importantly, what can I do to fix it?

Comment: I set up a single instance redis pod and used it for php session handling thinking I would be able to remove the session affinity if I did this. The redis session handling appears to be working but when I remove the session affinity the same old problems return. 

Each instance seems to maintain its own cart and wp login.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like woocommerce uses PHP sessions for Cart info:

https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/classes/WC-Cart.html#108
https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/classes/WC-Cart-Session.html

By default, that data would be stored on the specific pod file system. There are ways of telling PHP in multihost environments to use a common session store.

Comment: My understanding is that the woocommerce "session" relies on cookies as opposed to php sessions.

Comment: The cookie probably contains a key or token- this is to look up the session in a session store- which might be the file system on the server. Keeping actual cart data- which may have all kinds of verbose metadata, including images- in a cookie is typically not feasible.

Comment: And the woocommerce code snippets above are explicit in their use of the php session for the woocommerce cart.

Comment: I set up redis as a common session store but the problem returned as soon as I set session affinity to none.